# HTML/JS Kanban Board doesn't let me drop newly created tasks into other columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a Kanban Board in HTML/JS/CSS and am close to finishing my MVP here. Everything is working as expected, except for one thing. When I create a new task, I am able to drag it (seemingly) but not DROP it into any other columns. The sample tasks I have do not have this problem and I am ripping my hair out trying to figure out what the issue is. When I attempt to drag and drop newly created tasks into other columns, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at drop (/script.js:31:13)
    at HTMLDivElement.ondrop (/:45:112)
```

I am using basic drag and drop API stuff for HTML and JS and literally only need to make this work in order to finish my MVP. Any help is appreciated. NOTE: The line numbers in the above error change based on what column I try to drop the new task into but the error itself stays the same.

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Christopher's Kanban Board</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="new-task-window" id="new_task_form">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="title">New Task</div>
        <button class="btn-close-window" data-target="#new_task_form">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <input type="text" id="new-task-name" />
        <input type="submit" value="New Task" id="new-task-submit" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Kanban Board-->
    <div class="kanban-container">
      <div class="kanban-container-section" id="todo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <strong>To Do</strong>
        <div class="task-button-block">
            <button class="task-button" id="task-button" data-target="#new_task_form">+ New Task</button>
        </div>
        <div class="task" id="task1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <span contenteditable="true">Task #1</span>
            <!--<button class="edit_button" id="edit_button">Edit</button>-->
        </div>
        <div class="task" id="task2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <span contenteditable="true">Task #2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="task" id="task3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <span contenteditable="true">Task #3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="task" id="task4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
          <span contenteditable="true">Task #4</span>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="kanban-container-section" id="inprogress" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <strong>In Progress</strong>

      </div>
      <div class="kanban-container-section" id="done" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <strong>Done</strong>

      </div>
      <div class="kanban-container-section" id=" blocked" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <strong>Blocked</strong>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
const task = document.querySelector('.task');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-target]");
const close_buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-close-window");

//Allow the New Task Button to open the New Task Creation Window.
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector(btn.dataset.target).classList.add("active");
    overlay.classList.add("active");
  });
});

close_buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector(btn.dataset.target).classList.remove("active");
    overlay.classList.remove("active");
  });
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

const new_task_submit = document.getElementById("new-task-submit");
if(new_task_submit) {
  new_task_submit.addEventListener('click', createTask);
}

function createTask() {
  const task_div = document.createElement("div");
  const input_value = document.getElementById("new-task-name").value;

  //Take the text from the above input and create a task with that text.
  const text = document.createTextNode(input_value);

  task_div.appendChild(text);
  //Add the proper class (task in this case) to the newly created task.
  task_div.classList.add("task");
  //Add the draggable attribute to the newly created task and set it to true to allow drag and drop.
  if(task_div){
    task_div.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    task_div.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  }

  //task_div.innerHTML += `
  //<div class="task" id="${input_value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("")}"
  //draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)>
    //<span contenteditable="true">${input_value}</span>
  //</div>
  //`

  //Add the new task to the To Do section of the Kanban Board.
  const todo = document.getElementById("todo");
  todo.appendChild(task_div);

  document.getElementById("new-task-name").value = "";
  new_task_form.classList.remove("active");
  overlay.classList.remove("active");

}
```

style.css (the error would indicate that this file is not the problem):

```
.kanban-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.kanban-container-section {
  background: #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.kanban-container-section strong {
  background: #2C89BF;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task-button {
  width: 40%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
  border: 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task.button:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.btn-close-window {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-task-window {
  width: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.new-task-window.active {
  top: 15%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#overlay.active {
  display: block;
}

#new-task-name, #new-task-submit {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  align-items: center;
}

#new-task-submit {
  background-color: #2C89BF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Again, if anyone knows what my issue is here, the help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!